# Intent на вызов DownloadManager

Tags: android

Я создаю строку `Notifaction` для загрузки музыки. Мне нужно, чтобы при процессе загрузки, кликая на `Notifaction`, открывалась родное приложение `Downloads` так же, как в обычном браузере.

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

File downloadsManager = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
notificationIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(downloadsManager));

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
```

Пытался так, но не срабатывает, и так можно только открыть папку `Downloads` на SD карте.
Не могу использовать класс `DownloadManager` так, как API 8.

Answer (score 2):

DownloadManager запускается так:

```
Intent dm = new Intent(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
dm.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(dm);
```

Новая закачка в него добавляется так:

```
DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
mgr.enqueue(new Request(yourUri));
```

Не надо делать свой, стандартный справится.

Comment: уже сделал,DownloadManager нету в 8 Апи.

Answer (score 1):

`Intent` срабатывает на mime тип, который задается через `setData()`, в вашем случае вы даете интенту ссылку на файл соотвественно система просто понимает это как открыть каталог где лежит ваш файл.

Сильно глубоко тему `Notification` не копал, но примерно понимаю что надо задать урл на ваш контент (музыку или что там у вас) и задать экшн `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` (скачать) или ACTION_VIEW (открыть/проиграть), типа:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
intent.setDataAndType(myUri, "audio/mpeg"); //ссылка на файл + его тип (здесь MP3)
```

Comment: Я это реализовал при окончании загрузки,проигрывание музыки.
Но мне нужно при процессе загрузки переходить на приложение Downloads,как делает это обычный браузер.

Comment: Вам надо найти Action который вызывает браузер для Downloads. Все равно браузер использует интент с нужным экшном, на который и настроен Downloads. То есть если вы запустите интент с "правильным" экшном, то запустится Downloads

Comment: мне нужно реализовать свой DownloadsManager для браузера.

Comment: Ну так и сказали бы. Возьмите [исходники](http://necdroid.sourceforge.net/) и встройте в свой проект